# Why does this rose have 6 petals?

Tags: plotting

I'm guessing it gets drawn twice, but I can't see where

[image]

Comment: Because cosine goes positive and negative.

Comment: Sorry, how does that relate?

Comment: Oh, OK, that {1,-1} at the very beginning. I don't know what that is yet, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw the rose only once:

```
PolarPlot[{{1, -1} Cos[3 t], {1, -1}}, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
PolarPlot[{Cos[3 t], {1, -1}}, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: What does that {1,-1} do, exactly?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: The ` {1,-1}` draws the circle around the rose

Comment: No, the one _before_ Cos[3t], the one that returns 3 petals when you pull it :)

Comment: `{1, -1} Cos[3 t]` evaluates to `{Cos[3 t], -Cos[3 t]}`

Comment: OK, ty so much.

Comment: What version of Mathematica? Do not get circle with V11.1. `PolarPlot` was upgraded in 10.0? Are you using earlier version?

Comment: Hmm, strange - I have V 10.0